# Nominal type checking in C

Tags: c, types, warnings, lint

Typing checking in C/C++ is structural: what matters is that the denoted types, when all the `typedef` (whose name is really misleading) have been resolved, are the same.

Yet I have this program which uses many `list`s (of `void*`), many `int`s ranging over different types of objects, and I would very much like to have good `typedef`s for its lists (`typedef list foo_list`, `typedef list bar_list`) and its `int`s (`typedef int orange_number`, `typedef int apple_number`).  But it's easy to get it wrong.

I do not want to go for "strong typedefs", just being consistent in my uses of the type alias names.

Are there any compilers that feature warnings to complain about inconsistant type *names*?  Something that complain when I mix `orange_number` and `apple_number`, but not `orange_number` and `int`.  Is there anything that would prevent such a warning?

Comment: I don't think there's a compiler option for such warnings, but you could maybe write a compiler plugin for gcc/clang to add such warnings.

Comment: If `orange_number` and `apple_number` are in fact integer types, what is the rationale for convoluting them?

Comment: @vmt Being clear.

Comment: Please, do elaborate on how does this serve the purpose of clarity? In what particular case is (e.g.) `apple_number number` more clear than `int number`, given the context of a `list_of_apples` (or something similar)? To me, it would only seem to convolute the type so that a reader looking at the data structure also has to find the typedef.

Comment: For greater focus,, drop the "/C++" part.